# How can I run a Linksys USB adapter with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, usb

I am trying to run a Wireless G USB adapter with the Cisco Linksys version 3 WUSB54GC with Windows 8. I have had no success.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: For Super User to best help you, it would be helpful to know what you have tried so far?  One thing I have had success with in W8 is plugging in ethernet (if available) and trying to have Windows find a way to make it work.  But that device is fairly old and may not be supported.

Comment: All you need is a Windows 8 driver for the device.  If there isn't a Winodws 8 driver you can try a Windows 7 driver.  If that doesn't work then the device is not compatible with Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get my wusb54gc ver 3.0 running on a windows 8.1 64-bit PC by using the installer available at http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/adapters/WUSB54GC . However, I made sure to change the compatibility of the os to Windows Vista before running to ensure proper installation. I right clicked on the setup64 file > properties > compatibility > run this program in compatibility mode for windows vista (service pack 2).

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest (unofficial) driver from here:

https://sites.google.com/site/linksysupdateddrivers/rt2870/hardware/wusb54gc-v3

and try to install this driver.

Comment: Awesome. Not sure if this is marked as correct answer. Not sure if the question had negative votes. I couldn't find any other solution - and Linksys flat out said this is not supported, and the driver has been removed due to them not agreeing with GPL. But this worked, like a charm.

Thanks

Comment: @KalEl the user never came back and told us i the driver worked or not. But nice to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Windows 7 driver from [here](http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/adapters/WUSB54GC/download)

Just follow the instruction and it will enable the USB adapter. Alternatively you can download the setup wizard on the same page and it will guide you through the installation

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver in http://www.linksys.com/gr/support-article?articleNum=148577

**Dont use the setup**.  Install the driver manually from Device Manager.  Click in Browse my computer for Driver Software, and choose the Folder Setup.

Comment: Please don't use signatures in your future answers.  They will be removed so no real point